# OAuth to Tumblr API in order to get user's dashboard PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to make a Tumblr App that will get the user dashboard and will be able to present it in a different way. My problem is that i have absolutely no idea how to make an authentication to the user (oauth- get the access token and all that stuff). I can't understand how to do it from their website. Please Please help me understand how to do that, I really need that help

Answer (score 0):

First, there is the API docs on Tumblr.com:
https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

If you are using PHP, I can recommend the PHP OAuth Class on PHPClasses.org:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html

Along with the PHP Class mentioned above, you will also need the HTTP Client:
http://www.phpclasses.org/httpclient

Download both packages from PHPClasses.org and put them in a folder:

`/yourapp/...`

Go to https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps and register your app, make sure that the callback URL matches the url that you use for your script. (eg. http://domain.tld/folder/script.php)

Then take a look at the login_with_tumblr.php file from the OAuth Class that you downloaded, and change these values:

```
// your OAuth Consumer Key from https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps
$client->client_id = ''; 
// your OAuth Consumer Key from https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps
$client->client_secret = '';
```

Now load the script from the browser, it will initialize the Tumblr Oauth and authenticates you with the Consumer and Secret Key.

You now have access to Tumblr's API via PHP.

Good luck!